# SQL Server deadlock when using PreparedStatements

Tags: java, sql-server, concurrency, prepared-statement, database-deadlocks

I have a java servlet application and I'm using a prepared query to update a record in a SQL Server Database table.

Lets say I want to execute `UPDATE MyTable SET name = 'test' WHERE id = '10'`. (Yes, id is a varchar)

I used the following code to make this happen:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE MyTable SET name = ? WHERE id = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, getName() );
pstmt.setString(2, getID() );
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I found out that while I was running a JMeter script to simulate 2 users, this statement causes a deadlock in my database.

I wanted to check what my values were in the SQL Profiler so I used the following code, so I could check the values.

```
String query = String.format("UPDATE MyTable SET name = '%s' WHERE id = '%s' ", getName(), getID() );
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Suddenly my deadlock was gone! It's a shame the last approach is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Is there somebody who can tell me what is going on and/or how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by deadlock? How did you determine it was deadlocking?

Comment: I got an SQLException saying the transaction was deadlocked.

Comment: Are you sure that it was this change that made the deadlocks vanish? I'm pretty sure there is no way (excluding not committing transactions) that running the SQL you posted above would cause a deadlock.

Comment: Can you consistently reproduce the deadlock?  Like @DavidG, I'm having difficulty seeing why the deadlock is happening.

Comment: Yes this is what is happening people. Tried method 1 and 2 10 times and 10/10 is failing/succeeding.

Comment: And you did nothing in between switching methods?

Comment: Nope. Only those lines were edited.

Comment: Anything else accessing the database? That includes you with SSMS.

Comment: No not my database. Other users are using their own database on the same server, but even when I'm alone, the issue remains.

Comment: Is your code running inside a transaction then? Those statements shouln't deadlock anything as they are atomic operations.

Comment: I checked. But it is not the case. Creating the Connection -> creating the PreparedStatement -> Executing the PreparedStatement -> Closing the PreparedStatement -> Closing the Connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally found the problem and solution to my problem.

It seemed that the combination of the jTDS JDBC driver with MSSQL was the 'problem'.

[This article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207965) explained my situation exactly. And with the help of [this FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) I was able to set the datasource to the right configuration.

From what I understand:

If you have statement that uses a String-like index (Like in my situation), the table performs an index SCAN instead of an index SEEK. This causes the whole table to be locked and vulnerable to deadlocks.

I hope this will help other people too.